Windows 11 shortcuts on desktop not found via start search?
This seems so weird. I have some shortcuts on the desktop and when I click start or press win key, I just want to type beginning of those filenames and have it apper, but they don't! Seems like this always worked in Windows 10 and it does, when I try it on my other PC. Is this really removed in Win 11? Microsoft wants us to stop using desktop or what?

Microsoft wants us to stop using desktop or what? Yes, since always.

You determine what areas are indexed for Search: https://anytxt.net/manage-indexing-options-and-settings-for-windows-11-a-tutorial/ . Add the Desktop, or any other location to indexing.

"Choose Enhanced if you want to search your entire computer, or choose Classic if you need to search only pictures, music, documents, and desktop folders. "
seems like Desktop should already be there by default! But maybe because my Desktop is actually in OneDrive then it is not there...
